# Deployed Tomcat Webapp in EC2 can't talk to Postgres RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, network-security-groups

I have a simple Java servlet based app running on port 8080 of a tomcat server in an EC2.  When I click a button, it returns all user records in the database and renders them to the screen.

The app works fine when I deploy it on my localhost, with Tomcat, and it connects fine the RDS from which it's retrieving the user records.

However, when I deploy the WAR file to Tomcat on an EC2 instance and access it at http://51.***.***.***:8080/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, when I click the same button, it doesn't allow me to connect to my RDS and return the same objects.

**The EC2 and RDS instance share the same availability zone, VPC (default), and security groups.**
I even added the EC2's private IP address to the security group that specifies inbound rules for both the RDS and EC2 (Inbound: Postgres    5432   139.***.***.*** ).

I am connecting to my EC2 via AWS EC2 Instance Connect (not through bash on my localhost since an RDS is a managed service). I have installed maven, jdk8, tomcat, and git on the ec2....do I need to install postgres as well?

After copying the war file to `var/lib/tomcat/webapps` I run the app with `sudo service tomcat start` and can access it at port 8080 at the address I mentioned above. (`http://51.***.***.***:8080/MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`).

Below are the security group inbound rules that both the EC2 and RDS instance share:

[image: security group inbound rules]

What am I doing wrong in terms of allowing the EC2 and RDS to talk to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Had nothing to do with Security groups or VPC.  The servlet-based app in question is using URL rewriting to capture requests sent to http://543.251.123/AppToDeploy/...

```
        final String URI = request.getRequestURI().replace("/AppToDeploy/", ""); 
        
        switch(URI) {
        case "login":
            RequestHelper.processLogin(request, response);
            break;
            ...
```

Within the EC2 instance, when I ran `mvn clean package` it generated a WAR titled `AppToDeploy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`, which I passed to Tomcat's `webapps/` directory to serve on port 8080.

The fix was to add the following to my `pom.xml` file to rename the packaged war file.

```
    <build>
        <!-- This renames the built war file -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
```